# How to add a custom button to each row of a Telerik Grid?

Tags: button, grid, telerik

I  have a Telerik Grid control and I want to add a custom button for each row in the Grid, for Example "Employee Details", where on click on the "Employee Details" button I pass the Employee Id to another Razor page. How can I do it.?

I am using ASP.NET Core Razor pages.

Thanks,

Muder

grid to have a custom button